# how can i merge table with rows of null in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this, and I want to eliminate the nulls

```
id  myname yourname message
1   anna     null    hi
2   null     john    hi
3   anna     null    hello
4   null     john    hello
```

Row 1 & 2 are actually describing the same event, and so is row 3 & 4.

This is what I would like to get

```
id  myname yourname message
1   anna    john   hi
2   anna    john    hello
```

Can someone help...thanks!

Comment: Are the messages unique to each conversation? If not, how do you know which rows to merge?

Comment: let's assume it is in this example. My real table has also message id which is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you *merging* just two records you can use `MAX()` with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT MAX(myname) as me, MAX(yourname) as you, message
FROM theTable
GROUP BY message
```

Comment: hi, I tried this and it returns only 1 row? It would be cool if this works.

Comment: @minjiera Did you forget `GROUP BY message`?

Answer (score 0):

First copy `yourname` into the row with nulls:

```
UPDATE message_table m1
JOIN message_table m2 ON m1.message = m2.message
SET m1.yourname = m2.yourname
WHERE m1.yourname IS NULL;
```

Then delete the rows with `myname = NULL`:

```
DELETE FROM message_table
WHERE myname IS NULL;
```

Comment: hi silly question -- if message_table is a query result, how do i continue updating it?

Comment: Then you would put it as a subquery in the query in PM 77-1's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` for the aggregation.  This will work in your particular situation:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id,
       max(myname) as myname, max(yourname) as yourname, max(message) as message
from table t cross join (select @rn := 0) vars  
group by (case when t.id in (1, 2) then 1 else 2 end);
```

If you know the message is the same, you can aggregate by that.  However, in your question you seemed to suggest that the logic is based on `id` and not `message`.

Comment: thanks for answering. It doesn't really work.
the result I get is very interesting

 I get 2 rows but of the same message:
id  myname yourname message
1   anna       null          hello
2   anna       john         hello

Comment: Oops, I think the problem was the alias for `id` was the same as the table column.